# Angular / lodash - remove multiple objects from a collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**SOLUTION TO MY ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Thanks to the brilliance of Dan's answer below I've managed to reduce my original code significantly. I have dropped some of flexibility I originally had  built i.e. use multi properties vs static prop, but an easy fix in a later version and a no-brainer in terms of code size :) Again, many thanks to Dan. In this example I've included 2 `forget()` methods wrapped in an Angular Collection factory.

```
Collection.$inject = ['Constructor', 'Article'];
function Collection(Constructor, Article) {

    var Model = Article,
        Collection = {},
        collection = [],
        add,
        forget;

    function Extendable(data, keys) {
        Constructor.call(this, data, Model.fillable);
    }

    Extendable.prototype = Object.create(Constructor.prototype);
    Extendable.prototype.constructor = Extendable;
    Collection = Extendable.prototype;
    collection = Collection.items = [];

    add = function(item) {
        if (item instanceof Model) {
            collection.push(item);
        }
    };
    Collection.add = add;

    // EXAMPLE OF SINGLE ID DELETE I.E. SIMPLE VERSION
    forget = function(id) {
        collection = _.dropWhile(collection, {id: id});
    };
    Collection.forget = forget;

    // OR!!! EXAMPLE OF MULTI ID VALUE || ARRAY
    forget = function(id) {
        var ids = [];
        if (_.isArray(id)) {
            ids = id;
        } else {
            ids.push(parseInt(id));
        }
        return _.dropWhile(collection, function (n) {
            return _.includes(ids, n.id);
        });
    };
    Collection.forget = forget;

    // remove rest of factory for brevity sake
    return Extendable;
};
```

**DEV TOOLS**

Angular 1.4.8, lodash 2.x

**QUESTION:**

I'm still an Angular & JS. Is there a more concise approach to deleting multiple object instances (e.g. Article/s in a Articles Collection).  The `forget()` method accepts 1 argument that could a string||integer||array (of strings or integers)

**EXAMPLE:**

```
var articleIdsToRemove = [1, '2', 3];
```

OR

```
var articleIdsToRemove = 1; 

var articles = newCollection();
```

For brevity sake i've excluded the add method for adding Article instances to collection but lets assume we have 10, each with a prop of id

**MY CURRENT APPROACH**

1. validate type of value as above i.e. array, str, int, and set all values to an array of ints i.e. `ids`
2. then iterate through the array of ids to find an index for `Article`
   instance that has prop `id` and is equal to value `id`
3. if found push the index onto indices. One we have all matching
   indexes then send it  `Array.prototype.remove` to remove multiple
   items from the collection array. Once that is done then re-sort
   collection

removed Angular factory wrapper for brevity sake, but assume all of this is in a angular factory called Collection which injects an Article factory that is data model. In summary `Collection` (articles) contains many `Article`

```
    // We set a collections array inside of object to hold all Article instances
    collection = Extendable.prototype.items = [];
    // NOTE add articles method removed, but assume weve added multiple Article's to collection 

    forget = function(id) {
        var ids = [],
            index = null,
            indices = [];
        if (angular.isDefined(id) && !_.isEmpty(id)) {
            ids = _.isArray(id) ? id : isInt(id) ? [Number(id)] : [];
            if (ids.length) {
                _.each(ids, function(id) {
                    index = getIndex('app_id', id);
                    if (index) {
                        indices.push(index)
                    }
                });
                if (indices.length) {
                    collection = collection.remove(indices)
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Extendable.prototype.forget = forget;

    function isInt(n){
        return Number(n) === n && n % 1 === 0;
    }

    function getIndex(prop, value) {
        return _.indexOf(collection, function(d) {
            if (hasProp(d, prop)) {
                return d[prop] == value;
            }
        });
    }

    function hasProp (obj, prop) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
    }

    Array.prototype.remove = function(){
        var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
        var indices = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            var arg = args[i];
            var index = this.indexOf(arg);
            while(index > -1){
                indices.push(index);
                index = this.indexOf(arg, index + 1);
            }
        }
        indices.sort();
        for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){
            var index = indices[i] - i;
            this.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this

```
var forget = function(id) {
  var ids = [];
  if (_.isArray(id)) {
    ids = id;
  } else {
    ids.push(parseInt(id));
  }
  return _.dropWhile(articles, function(n) {
    return _.includes(ids, n.id);
  });
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hFm7j/226/

Comment: Won't this only remove an element till the predicate returns false? If the array was built by a user selecting articles for instance, the ids could be out of order, so calling `forget(['4',3'])` in your example wouldn't remove anything. I think `_.reject` would be more fitting instead of `_.dropWhile`.